# Integration demonstration on my Calculus exam

Tags: calculus

Good morning,

I had this demonstration to do on my calculus exam.

$$I_n=\int x^ne^{ax^2}$$

This integration is equal to:
$$I_n=\frac{1}{2a}x^{n-1}e^{ax^2}-\frac{n-1}{2a}
I_{n-2}.$$

Please help me.

Comment: Please use  [Mathjax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-qu%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bick-reference) for typing your question.

Comment: What is the question? Are you asking how to derive that expression for $I_n$ in terms of $I_{n-2}$?

Comment: @almagest I think he meant $ I_n = \displaystyle\int x^n e^{ax^2} \mathrm{d}x $ .

Comment: If it's for an exam, ask the professor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $$I_n=\int x^ne^{ax^2}dx$$ use integration by parts $$u=x^{n-1}\implies u'=(n-1)x^{n-2}$$ $$v'=x e^{ax^2}dx\implies v=\frac{e^{a x^2}}{2 a}$$ I am sure that you can take it from here.

Comment: I doubt it, since this is a really simple case of integration by parts!

Comment: @almagest. I agree that this is probably one of the simplest cases. Cheers.